# Update manager - Failed to load package list

Tags: apt, update-manager

Come to do some updates in 12.10 today and get the error

```
E:Malformed Description-md5 line; includes invalid character 'd72e12fa21290d21a54b'4e8480abad1', E:Malformed Description-md5 line; includes invalid character 'd72e12fa21290d21a54b'4e8480abad1', E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.

This is from either update manager or apt-get (which gives a bit more info)

Malformed Description-md5 line; includes invalid character 'd72e12fa21290d21a54b'4e8480abad1'
    Malformed Description-md5 line; includes invalid character 'd72e12fa21290d21a54b'4e8480abad1'
    The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
    Can't call method "policy" on an undefined value at /usr/bin/apt-show-versions line 56.
    E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'test -x /usr/bin/apt-show-versions || exit 0 ; apt-show-versions -i'
    E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

Any suggestions as to what has gone wrong and how to get round it?

Cheers

Iain

Comment: So what is workaround???

Comment: Please post your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.

Comment: Closed as "too localized"? It's certainly not geographically or temporally localized. And it's "generally applicable", still: 17 releases later! These situations happen **all** the time, and nobody is helped by preventing users from discussing workarounds and fixes.